# Followed GraphQL tutorial / Resolver object to query MySQL DB fails

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, resolver

Developing entirely local, I followed the tutorial here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/super-simple-graphql-with-node#toc-creating-the-graphql-server

Hardly any modification, only to restrict the focus to a "product" table.  No "User" or "Recipe" table.

It appears the only issue I have now is retrieving the data from the MySQL DB.

Of course I've Googled and compared tutorials extensively.  I've been through the code quite a bit as well to the point it's getting blurry.

If I change the "return" to  {"name":"test"}, the data passes through to my local GraphQL dashboard perfectly.

models/index.js

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};
let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
    sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}
fs.readdirSync(__dirname).filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
}).forEach(file => {
    const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
}); //console.log(db);                                                                                                                                                      Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {                                                                                                                                    if (db[modelName].associate) {                                                                                                                                            db[modelName].associate(db);                                                                                                                                          }                                                                                                                                                                     });                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             db.sequelize = sequelize;                                                                                                                                               db.Sequelize = Sequelize;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
module.exports = db;
```

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Product = sequelize.define('Product', {
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        urlWordRef: DataTypes.STRING,
        seoTitle: DataTypes.STRING,
        seoDescription: DataTypes.STRING,
        standardEquipment: DataTypes.STRING,
        technicalSpecs: DataTypes.STRING
    }, {});
    Product.associate = function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        //Product.hasMany(models.RefProductOptions)
    };
    return Product;
};
```

```
// src/resolvers.js
const resolvers = {               
    Query: {
        async products (root, { id }, { models }) {
            return models.Products.findById(id) // *** THE LINE OF CODE WHICH FAILS ***
            return {"name":"test"} // ** SUBSTITUTING THE ABOVE LINE WITH THIS - SUCCESS!  ***
        }       
    }     
}                                    
module.exports = resolvers
```

```
// src/schema.js
const { gql } = require('apollo-server')
const typeDefs = gql `
    type Products {
        id: Int!
        name: String
        urlWordRef: String
        seoTitle: String
        seoDescription: String
        standardEquipment: String
        technicalSpecs: String
    }
    type Query {
        products(id: Int!): Products
    }
`;
module.exports = typeDefs
```

```
// src/index.js
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server')
const typeDefs = require('./schema')
const resolvers = require('./resolvers')
const models = require('../models')
const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: { models }
})
server.listen({port: 4000}).then(({ url }) => console.log('Server is running on localhost:4000'))
```

GraphQL query via the dashboard:

```
{
  products(id: 1) {
    name
  }
}
```

I would expect that I can pass the id via the noted GRaphQL query above and get the correct table row result.

Alas, I'm ready to start coding with my forehead!

---

Error response in GraphQL:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot read property 'findById' of undefined",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "products"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "stacktrace": [
            "TypeError: Cannot read property 'findById' of undefined",
            "    at products (/home/bob/graphql-server/src/resolvers.js:6:26)",
            "    at field.resolve (/home/bob/graphql-server/node_modules/graphql-extensions/dist/index.js:140:26)",
            "    at resolveFieldValueOrError (/home/bob/graphql-server/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:486:18)",
            "    at resolveField (/home/bob/graphql-server/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:453:16)",
            "    at executeFields (/home/bob/graphql-server/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:294:18)",
            "    at executeOperation (/home/bob/graphql-server/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:238:122)",
            "    at executeImpl (/home/bob/graphql-server/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:85:14)",
            "    at Object.execute (/home/bob/graphql-server/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:62:35)",
            "    at /home/bob/graphql-server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:239:46",
            "    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)",
            "    at /home/bob/graphql-server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:7:71",
            "    at new Promise (<anonymous>)",
            "    at __awaiter (/home/bob/graphql-server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:3:12)",
            "    at execute (/home/bob/graphql-server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:218:20)",
            "    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bob/graphql-server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:156:42)",
            "    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)",
            "    at fulfilled (/home/bob/graphql-server/node_modules/apollo-server-core/dist/requestPipeline.js:4:58)",
            "    at <anonymous>",
            "    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "products": null
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code

Comment: Sorry Daniel, I had pulled in some odd characters throwing it all off.  It's now cleaned up.  Thanks.

Comment: So what exactly is failing? Are any errors being returned in the response? If there is a stack trace, you should include that in your question as well. If the response is not returning the expected data, what is the response and what were you expecting?

Comment: Apologies.  I'm more tired than I realized.  I've added the error response above.

Comment: No worries. What is exported inside `models/index.js`? Based on the error, the object returned by `require('../models')` does not have a property named `Products`. You can `console.log` the `models` variable before passing it to context to see its actual shape.

Comment: Yea, I did that before looking for something obvious. (console.log)  It's huge.   I'll muster and dig back in.  Thanks Daniel.

Comment: The model is named `Product`, but you're trying to access `Products` inside the resolver.

Comment: I found that I had named the model reference in "Product", not "Products".   New error response now: 
"message": "models.Products.findById is not a function",

Comment: if you're using a newer version of Sequelize, it's `findByPk`, not `findById`. See the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html).

Comment: Aw man!   Talk about a nice gift Daniel!  Ok, I have other issues now, but I think you've saved my bacon.

Comment: Hey Daniel, I had a follow up issue I could use your insight with.  Been through docs and what not.   Mind taking a look?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56758931/why-is-refproductoptions-getproductoptions-is-not-a-function-in-this-graphql-r